# Sequential Compression Device (SCD) records in MIMIC

Tags: mimic-iii

I am trying to determine if ICU patients were issued sequential compression devices (SCD). Is this information captured anywhere other than the TEXT field in the NOTEEVENTS table within the MIMIC database?

Answer (score 2):

In CareVue, sequential compression devices are documented in the `chartevents` table:

- `itemid` = 49, `label` = "Anti-Embolism [Device]", `value` = (Ace Wrap, Elastic Stocking, None/Remarks, **Compress Sleeves**)
- `itemid` = 8367, `label` = "Anti-Embolism [Status]", `value` = (On, Off, Other/Remarks).

For Metavision patients, the following `itemid`s are present in the `d_items` tables and relate to sequential compression devices:

- `itemid` = 225054, `label` = "Anti Embolic Device Status"
- `itemid` = 224089, `label` = "Anti Embolic Device"

In MIMIC-III v1.3 these `itemid`s do not link to associated values unfortunately, due to issues with the raw data dump. The missing data should be added in the next release (v1.4).